# Текст на кнопке пропадает с телефона

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация

У меня проблема с текстом на кнопке. Если заходить с любого браузера на телефоне, текст на кнопке появляется на 1 секунду, и пропадает.

На компьютере всё нормально (даже если сжимать разрешение на компьютере - тоже всё супер), но когда запускаю на телефоне сайт, то возникает проблема с кнопкой.

```
<button id="gooey-button">
            YouTube
                <span class="bubbles">
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                    <span class="bubble"></span>
                </span>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                <defs>
                    <filter id="gooey">
                        <!-- in="sourceGraphic" -->
                        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="6" result="blur" />
                        <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="highContrastGraphic" />
                        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="highContrastGraphic" operator="atop" />
                    </filter>
                </defs>
            </svg>
            </button>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4000px;
  left: -4000px; }

#gooey-button {
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  filter: url("#gooey");
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffa72c; }
  #gooey-button:focus {
    outline: none; }
  #gooey-button .bubbles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; }
    #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble {
      background-color: #ffa72c;
      border-radius: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      z-index: -1; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(1) {
        left: 93px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-1 3.02s infinite;
        animation-delay: 0.2s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(2) {
        left: 35px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-2 3.04s infinite;
        animation-delay: 0.4s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(3) {
        left: 68px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-3 3.06s infinite;
        animation-delay: 0.6s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(4) {
        left: 93px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-4 3.08s infinite;
        animation-delay: 0.8s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(5) {
        left: 84px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-5 3.1s infinite;
        animation-delay: 1s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(6) {
        left: 82px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-6 3.12s infinite;
        animation-delay: 1.2s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(7) {
        left: 47px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-7 3.14s infinite;
        animation-delay: 1.4s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(8) {
        left: 38px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-8 3.16s infinite;
        animation-delay: 1.6s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(9) {
        left: 20px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-9 3.18s infinite;
        animation-delay: 1.8s; }
      #gooey-button .bubbles .bubble:nth-child(10) {
        left: 33px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: move-10 3.2s infinite;
        animation-delay: 2s; }

@keyframes move-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -66px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -56px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -89px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-4 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -125px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-5 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -52px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-6 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -79px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-7 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -56px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-8 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -123px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-9 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -109px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes move-10 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0); }
  99% {
    transform: translate(0, -111px); }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0; } }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Comment: может кэш, неее?

Comment: Заметил что данная проблема только на IOS. На Android всё работает корректно. Кэш очищал, заходил с разных Айфонов.